# Styled-Components & React: how to avoid cluttering?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I've recently started to use Styled Components together with React, and I am unsure if I am handling a particular case right which keeps reoccuring.

Let's say I have a very simple component like a `Label` which needs only a very styles and some given content. I would now handle this is follows:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export type Props = {...};

export const Impl = styled.span`
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 4px;
  ...
`;

export const Label: React.FC<Props> = ({ text }) => <Impl>{ text }</Impl>;
```

I find it circumstantial to define base components like `Impl` first, only for the styles, and then then another component which takes the props and uses that styled component.

Is there a shorter way to do both in only one component? I was hoping for something like ...

```
export const Label = styled.span<Props>=`
  ...styles...
`({ label }) = { label };
```

... but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You could use [`.attrs()`](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#attaching-additional-props) to select `children` from the props, but see if you can figure out how to enforce the types: `const Label = styled.span.attrs({ children: (props) => props.text })\`display: inline-block;\`;`

Comment: Looks like latest styled-components' `.attrs` takes in a function: `styled.span.attrs((props: Props) => ({ children: props.text }))\`display: inline-block;\``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could do this is to use the `styled` factory and just inline your component - though this kind of inverses the relation in the sense that you're not using a `styled.span`, but rather just styling your own component via the `className` generated by `styled-components`. This also means that you need to include `className?` in your props' type, or use an utility type to add it in.

```
type Props = {
  text: string;
  className?: string;
};

const Label = styled(({ text, className }: Props) => (
  <span className={className}>{text}</span>
))`
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 4px;
  color: red;
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Label text="foo" />
    </>
  );
}
```

You might also prefer this:

```
const Label = styled(({ text, ...props }: Props) => (
  <span {...props}>{text}</span>
))`
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 4px;
  color: red;
`;
```

or with a utility type:

```
type SCP<T> = T & { className?: string };

type Props = {
  text: string;
};

const Label = styled(({ text, ...props }: SCP<Props>) => (
  <span {...props}>{text}</span>
))`
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 4px;
  color: red;
`;
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for your time & support, @cbr, I wasn't aware of the factory function; that looks like a pretty cool solution!

Comment: @JohnGoofy You can also use it with any other component that passes `className` on :) e.g. `styled(Component)`